# Duplicates ID checking

Tags: r

I have data with a list of people's names and their ID numbers. Some people are listed twice or three times. Each person has an ID number - if they are listed more than once, as long as it is the same person, their ID number will stay the same. Like this:

```
Name  david david john john john john megan bill barbara chris chris

ID     1      1    2    2    2    2   3    4    5   6   6
```

I need to make sure that these ID numbers are correct and that different people do not have the same ID numbers. In doing so, I want to create a new variable that assigns new ID numbers so that I can compare the new ID numbers with the old ones. I want to create a command that says 
"if their names are the same, make their ID numbers the same". 
How do I do this? Does this make sense?

Comment: unique name , add id , and merge it back

Comment: I wouldn't be able to merge after using unique(name) to the original data set because then the length would be different?

Comment: You would be able to merge. Merge is a lookup function based on common values. Similar to dlookup in Access or vlookup and hlookup in Excel or Calc.

Comment: `merge(dat,uniquedata,by.x='name',by.y='uniquename',all.x=T)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, some of them were suggested above. I typically use a `dplyr` version to spot and remove duplicates / bad cases. Here is an example with various outputs, depending on your objective.

```
library(dplyr)

# example with one bad case
dt = data.frame(Name = c("david","davud","John","John","megan"),
                ID = c(1,1,2,3,3), stringsAsFactors = F)


# spot names with more than 1 unique IDs
dt %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(NumIDs = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  filter(NumIDs > 1)

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#    Name NumIDs
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1  John      2


# spot names with more than 1 unique IDs and the actual IDs
dt %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(NumIDs = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  filter(NumIDs > 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#    Name    ID NumIDs
#   <chr> <dbl>  <int>
# 1  John     2      2
# 2  John     3      2


# spot names with more than 1 unique IDs and the actual IDs - alternative
dt %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(NumIDs = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  filter(NumIDs > 1) %>%
  group_by(Name, NumIDs) %>%
  summarise(IDs = paste0(ID, collapse=",")) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#      Name NumIDs   IDs
#     <chr>  <int> <chr>
#   1  John      2   2,3
```